# Provider gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Tags: android

`java.lang.SecurityException: Provider gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission` exepction is thrown at this line`Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

The problem is my manifest is definitely correct. I'm running Android 4.0.4 Sony Ericsson xperia arc s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.appointify.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the phone was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line in manifest.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: No. `Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates)

Comment: did you enabled your location in android phone.

Comment: Yes, I do have it enabled.

Comment: shutdown the phone and restart it. this is the bug in the phones.

Comment: Already tried this, not working. But it's working on my Samsung Galaxy S3 mini...